# Firestore does not return all elements instead it is returning only the updated element, whenever I make an update to a document in a collection

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am listening to changes in the database and using a Streambuilder to display it, Everything works when I navigate to the widget, and when I rebuild the widget, but whenever I am on the widget and update a document, new data is sent, bu I get only that document I updated, and not the whole document in the collection.

so say I have four documents, and updates the 2nd one, I only see that second on, to view all of them again I will have to navigate away from the screen and back

here is my fuction for fetching all documents ==>

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> fetchAllConversations(String userId) {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    return firestore
        .collection(userNode)
        .document(userId)
        .collection(conversationNode)
        .orderBy("lastMessageDate", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }

//here is my stream builder for listening to the collection

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: convoDao.fetchAllConversations(session.currentUserId),
              builder: (context, stream) {
                if (stream.hasData) {
                  if (stream.data.documentChanges.isEmpty) {
                    return Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text("No active conversations"));
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: stream.data.documentChanges.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ActiveChatListItem(convo: ConvoDTO.fromJson(                      stream.data.documentChanges[index].document.data));
                      });
                }

                if (stream.hasError) { //todo: handle error
                }

                return loading();
              })),
```

How can I keep getting the whole document in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user `stream.data.documents` instead of `stream.data.documentChanges`

**Document comment for documentChanges**

> /// An array of the documents that changed since the last snapshot. If this
>     /// is the first snapshot, all documents will be in the list as Added changes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I missed something like that... I need a long break

Comment: You are welcome!.. Some days are like that. Follow me on twitter @nonybrighto. Might be coming to Enugu very soon